# Passed ng-style in directive template causes Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to pass styles via ng-style to a directive template.

```
 .directive('ngFiledialog', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                ...
                modalstyle: '='    // using '@' doesn't change the style?!
            },
            templateUrl: '/templates/filedialog.html',
            controller: FileDialogController
        }
    })
```

Filedialog.html:

```
...<div class="modal-dialog" ng-style="modalstyle">...</div>...
```

Using the directive:

```
<ng-filedialog id="testdialog2" ...   modalstyle="{'width':'1200px'}"></ng-filedialog>
```

Style is applied when using '=' in scope but I get errors:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}; oldVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}; oldVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}; oldVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}; oldVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}; oldVal: {\"width\":\"1200px\"}"]]
```

Comment: The code you are showing is fine. Maybe you do something in controller?

Comment: any idea why using '@' does not work?